# Django e-commerce 1.2, missing settings.py file

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the Django 1.2 e-commerce book by Jesse Legg.
I have used Django before and had no problems doing the usual basic stuff (admin apps etc).
However I'm stumped on this one.

Near the bottom of Page 17 it says:
"""
we will create our settings file and a root URLs file in our project module:
ecommerce_book/settings.py and ecommerce_book/urls.py. It is recommended
that you copy these files from the companion source code.
"""
The settings.py file is not in the companion source code. I have emailed the author and Packt but so far no reply.

Does anybody know how to locate this settings.py file?

I'm familiar with the usual method suggested i.e.
python django-admin.py startproject ecommerce_book

However, the author seems to be saying there is a custom settings.py file which needs to be used in this particular case. (but it's not included in the downloaded source code)

Answer (score 1):

```
python django-admin.py startproject ecommerce_book
```

Though I'm not sure this initial `settings.py` will be the same you want. To the praticular `settings.py` contact authors or publishing.

Comment: the author seems to be saying there is a custom settings.py file which needs to be used in this particular case. (but it's not included in the downloaded source code)